# Table Search JS ou jQuery

Tags: javascript, algoritmo-de-busca, table

Estou a querer fazer código de um search recorrendo a um RegEX para strings, e de numeros normais, e que porcuro pelas colunas e linhas da tabela.

Já tentei variadissimas hipóteses, mas nenhuma faz aquele "refresh" de voltar ao inicio quando apago a palavra ou numero que esteja a procura.

Deixo uma pequena print / código:

[image: Tabela com o seu respectivo search]
O Código é este:

```
 <div class="row">
      <div class="containerSearch">
          <input type="text" id="searchTabela" placeholder="Search" data-table="resultsTable" />
           <button class="iconSearch"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
      </div>
      <table id="tabelaProgramas" class="table table-hover text-center resultsTable" style="width: 100%">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th class="text-center">Top</th>
                                            <th class="text-center"></th>
                                            <th class="text-center">Program</th>
                                            <th class="text-center">Start</th>
                                            <th class="text-center">Length</th>
                                            <th class="text-center">Rat%</th>
                                            <th class="text-center">Shr%</th>
                                            <th class="text-center">Rch%</th>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr class="warning no-result text-center">
                                            <td colspan="8"><i class="fa fa-warning"></i>Sem resultados obtidos!</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>1</td>
                                            <td>
                                                <img src="img/logo_tvi.png" class="img-responsive" style="margin: 0 auto;" /></td>
                                            <td>Jornal das 8</td>
                                            <td><i class="fa fa-clock-o icontabelaProgramas" style="color: #8EC127;"></i>19:56:02</td>
                                            <td><i class="fa fa-arrows-h icontabelaProgramas"></i>01:47:57</td>
                                            <td><i class="fa fa-line-chart icontabelaProgramas" style="color: #8EC127;"></i>13.4</td>
                                            <td><i class="fa fa-line-chart icontabelaProgramas" style="color: #8EC127;"></i>28.8</td>
                                            <td><i class="fa fa-line-chart icontabelaProgramas" style="color: #8EC127;"></i>29.4</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>2</td>
                                            <td>
                                                <img src="img/logo_rtp1.png" class="img-responsive" style="margin: 0 auto;" /></td>
                                            <td>Jornal das 8</td>
                                            <td><i class="fa fa-clock-o icontabelaProgramas" style="color: #8EC127;"></i>19:56:02</td>
                                            <td><i class="fa fa-arrows-h icontabelaProgramas"></i>01:47:57</td>
                                            <td><i class="fa fa-line-chart icontabelaProgramas" style="color: #8EC127;"></i>13.4</td>
                                            <td><i class="fa fa-line-chart icontabelaProgramas" style="color: #8EC127;"></i>28.8</td>
                                            <td><i class="fa fa-line-chart icontabelaProgramas" style="color: #8EC127;"></i>29.4</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>3</td>
                                            <td>
                                                <img src="img/logo_rtp2.png" class="img-responsive" style="margin: 0 auto;" /></td>
                                            <td>Jornal das 8</td>
                                            <td><i class="fa fa-clock-o icontabelaProgramas" style="color: #8EC127;"></i>19:56:02</td>
                                            <td><i class="fa fa-arrows-h icontabelaProgramas"></i>01:47:57</td>
                                            <td><i class="fa fa-line-chart icontabelaProgramas" style="color: #8EC127;"></i>13.4</td>
                                            <td><i class="fa fa-line-chart icontabelaProgramas" style="color: #8EC127;"></i>28.8</td>
                                            <td><i class="fa fa-line-chart icontabelaProgramas" style="color: #8EC127;"></i>29.4</td>
                                        </tr>

                                        //Os outros tr's são iguas, são um exemplo

                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
```

Sei que existe jQuery plug-ins, mas gostava de praticar a lógica e para tal peço-vos ajuda. Já vi algum código, uns fizeram-me sentido, só que não se aplicam bem e é aí que fico ainda mais confuso. Alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: O que queres que aconteça quando houver match? esconda as outras?

Comment: @Sergio exacto, que esconda aquelas que não teem match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cria um objeto com os dados dessa tabela para acelerar o processamento mais tarde. Na minha sugestão criei uma array de objetos. Cada objeto tem o elemento `tr` e o conteudo dessa linha.

```
var $linhas = $('#tabelaProgramas tr');
var tabela = $('#tabelaProgramas tr').map(function (i, tr) {
    return {
        el: tr,
        conteudo: $(tr).text()
    }
}).get();
```

Depois no `keyup` podes percorrer essa array e mostrar só os elementos que têm texto eom comum com o que foi pedido no input:

```
$('#searchTabela').on('keyup', function (e) {
    var searchString = this.value;
    var linhas = tabela.filter(function (tr) {
        return tr.conteudo.indexOf(searchString) != -1;
    }).map(function (l) {
        return l.el;
    });
    $linhas.hide();
    $(linhas).show();
});
```

#### Exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/h6onh7gm/

Comment: Isso também conta com espaços? Ou seja neste caso se puser "jornaldas8" supostamente não deve encontrar, porque existe é "Jornal das 8". E pode ser uppercase ou lowercase que é igual. Ou seja, pesquisar "jornal das 8" é igual a pesquisar "JoRnAl dAs 8" entendes? Obrigado pela ajuda prestada! :)

Comment: @n1c0t0p a minha sugestão implica que o texto tem de ser exatamente igual ao que tens na tabela. Se quiseres ser mais permissivo ignorando espaços ou letras grandes, etc então tens de dar exemplos do comportamento que queres para o código ser ajustado.

Comment: É apenas ignorar as letras serem grandes ou pequenas e sempre com espaços basicamente. Por exemplo, se tiver na tabela "Pedro Cruz", Eu vou pesquisar "pedro" encontro na tabela, se pesquisar "pEdRo" também encontro. Ou seja, não é case sensitive.

Existe outro caso. No meu thead tenho uma div "no-result" que só poderá ser chamada (ou seja, mudando o display/visibility, neste caso display) Quando este não encontrar a palavra.

Obrigado mais uma vez @Sergio

Comment: @n1c0t0p -> https://jsfiddle.net/h6onh7gm/1/

Comment: É mesmo isto. Obrigado @Sergio , falei cntg no fb, assim que tiver mais tempo falo cntg. Muito Obrigado mesmo! ;)